# How do I overcome the weaknesses of the single page application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, core-ui

I want to build a single page application with vue https://vuetifyjs.com/en/ or https://coreui.io/vue/. but some references say that single page application is not good in SEO. so I thought about using it. perhaps the best solution is to use a multi page application. if that is the best choice, what is the best technology to use vue to develop multi page applications? The API is already available, so I just use it

please provide some of the best options. so I can have several options. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While others have chimed in with SSR solutions, another route you could take is using prerendering.  [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) is a web pack plugin that can be used for this, which takes in the routes you'd like to render, and generates the HTML and JS files for it.

There is also [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io), which intercepts requests from web crawlers and prerenders the SPA before serving it to the crawler. This service is free for up to 250 pages, and takes almost all the complexity away from the developer.

These can both be fantastic options if you're new to Vue, don't want to manage the complexity of server side rendering, or don't want to get into using something like Nuxt for static site generation.

The company I work at uses Nuxt (we use universal mode, also known as server side rendering), but we've also been very happy with the static site rendering it can do using [generate](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering-) for our random smaller projects.  Just be aware that this comes with the added complexity of another framework built on top of Vue, and plenty of extra hurdles that accompany that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. like that is the best and fast solution. because if I use Nuxt, maybe I will take a lot of time. I will try to implement prerender. btw, to use this solution, it doesn't take long?

Comment: The prerender-spa-plugin has a Vue and vue-router example listed in the readme of the repo you can copy.  It's just a Webpack plugin, so assuming you've set your project up with the vue-cli, you should be able to follow their documentation for extending the Webpack config.  Prerender.io does require a server, but if you use Netlify.com for hosting (free and simple), they provide Prerender.io as part of their service

Comment: Okay thanks. Seems I can using your answer. So I will using prerender. because my project is only a month. so I need a quick and easy solution

Comment: btw do you have the option to create an easy css display? for example coreui or vuetify. Do you have other options?

Comment: Prerendering, SSR, and SPA's are all CSS agnostic, and should work with any extra libraries you choose to pick up.  However, I don't have much experience with them as we use a custom solution.  You may want to ask another question regarding this, or try digging into them to see what works best for your use case.

Comment: yes. I just want to be sure. I want to know a few options. so I can make the right decision

Comment: @HMilbradt Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524595/how-can-i-implement-server-side-rendering-ssr-on-the-vuetify-project-that-is-1

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that a standard VueJS-SPA is bad for SEO, as the first HTML is usually delivered empty and only when the Vue-code is downloaded and executed, your page will be dynamically rendered and mounted on the client.

Building a multi-page (as in every route leads to a  completely new HTML page being sent down by the server) is not really feasible with Vue though.

Instead, I would advise to look into Server-Side-Rendering for VueJS. This can be achieved with [standard VueJS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) or with a framework that is specialized in this such as [NuxtJS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html).

What this technique will effectively do is that it will render the first page, the user visits on the server and send down the rendered HTML. This will lead to good SEO, as the crawler receives a rendred HTML page every time. For every subsequent page-navigation the site will then simply behave like an SPA.

Comment: so your solution is using nuxtjs? If I use it, what UI is used for display? can it use coreui or vuetify?

Comment: Yes, I would definitely go with nuxt. When you create an app with `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`, you will actually be asked if you want to use vuetify and it will then set it all up for you. You can read more about [scaffolding a nuxt app here.](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation)

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to SEO with SPAs is to enable server-side rendering of your SPA. This works by having your HTTP server serve the fully rendered application to the client; rather, than sending boilerplate HTML and then having the client make subsequent requests for app bundles and whatnot.

Comment: do you mean if I enable  that, then the single page application will be seo friendly? I can ask for the detail link/reference how to do it

Comment: @Shon Verch Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524595/how-can-i-implement-server-side-rendering-ssr-on-the-vuetify-project-that-is-1